# What IP address will show up in the Log

Tags: vpn, server, ip

I have a conundrum going on in my head for sometime now.

It involves IP addresses, VPN and VPS.

The scenario is this:

I have two Virtual Private Servers (VPS), let's call them VPS 1 and VPS X.

Now, let's say the following are the IP Addresses of each machines:

- my Desktop's = 192.69.69.69
- VPS 1's = 192.39.39.39
- VPS X's = 192.75.75.75

**(A) My first question is**, if I use my desktop to remote desktop connect to VPS 1, what is the IP address that will show up in VPS 1's (access) log?

*If my wild guess is correct, it's 192.69.69.69. But I still need confirmation that my answer is correct.*

(B) Then after connecting to VPS1, I successfully set up a Virtual Private Network (VPN) inside VPS 1. I have no question about this. :)

**(C) Second question**, Using the VPN i just set up in VPS1, I used my desktop and connected to VPN X, what's the IP address that will show up in VPS X's (access) log?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the configuration of the vpn, and Amazon.

### 1st Question:

**yes**, it should be

If not, Amazon is using some gateways/loadbalancer in front of VPS1.
But I would think, that this is *very* unlikely.

### 2nd Question:

In a normal vpn gateway configuration it would be **VPS 1's IP**

If it is correctly configured VPS 1 *can* pass the IP of your computer to the Backend (VPS X). This isn't usually the case.

Again, if this is a special Amazon-related software it *could be* something else.

Comment: Thank you Ludwig, thank you for giving your answer. Assuming its not Amazon. another question please, is there a way that my original IP (192.69.69.69) will be traced that it logged in to VPS X?

Comment: @BenDaggers I updated my answer. It *could be* possible. Both VPS 1 and VPS X would need configurations for that.